# RTF table header row

Tags: rtf

I am using xslt to render an xml file to rtf, which is mainly made up of tables. I would like to be able to render the table headers where the table goes over a page break, using rtf/Words native functionality. I have tried \trhdr but this does not do what I expect, or I am not using it correctly, and in fact I am not sure if what I am trying to do is possible.

`<xsl:variable name="headerRowCall">
      <xsl:text>\trowd\trgaph75\trhdr\trleft8\trbrdrl\brdrs\brdrw15\brdrcf2 \trbrdrt\brdrs\brdrw15\brdrcf2 \trbrdrr\brdrs\brdrw15\brdrcf2 \trbrdrb\brdrs\brdrw15\brdrcf2 \trpaddl75\trpaddr75\trpaddfl3\trpaddfr3 </xsl:text>
    </xsl:variable>`

Comment: After some more experimentation it would appear that **\thdr** might be restricted to one per document and is not over written...

Comment: something else going on here, checking what blank cells do...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lay out required a table row containing the table name and a header giving the units. I was trying to get only the units row to render at the page break, but the head also needs an to be included, which does make sense.